# Is this the right way to block user-agents I find on my logs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite, block

I want to block several agents that I have seen in my server logs,
their exact names in the logs were, for example:

`Python-urllib/2.6`

`Python-urllib/2.7`

`CATExplorador/1.0beta (sistemes at domini dot cat; http://domini.cat/catexplorador.html)`

I've seen [this example](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml), but not sure how to implement it,
should it be exactly as they appeared:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Python-urllib/2.6 [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Python-urllib/2.7 [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^CATExplorador/1.0beta (sistemes at domini dot cat; http://domini.cat/catexplorador.html) [OR] 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

**Or would this be good as well:**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^python [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^catexplorador [OR] 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Questions for example:

1. If I want to block all versions of this "python" (or all agents
   containing that string), would the second code work?
2. are the names case-sensitive?  (catexplorador vs CATExplorador vs CaTExplorador)
3. Are these the right flags?
4. how to block "blank" user agents? (is it recommended?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block all agents starting with `python` OR `catexplorador` and making it case insensitive you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(python|catexplorador) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Comment: thanks, though a. what is the motivation for using the first code pattern? e.g, [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml), why won't he use your pattern? b. he also got `Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com` - how would that be blocked with your method (i'm afraid `(bot|` would block googlebot as well)? c. does `(pytho|` includes `python` and would block it as well?

Comment: a) Better to use regex support than writing so many separate `RewriteCond` lines. b) For blocking that you can write: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(python|catexplorador|Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo\.com) [NC]` c) Yes it will.

Comment: a. is there anything in the code that signifies a "wildcard" which means that `ab|` would block `abc` and `abjjjd`? I'm trying to understand the logic. b. "regex" is your `|` method? c. what do you think about the second answer that suggests some different rule? thanks!

Comment: a) In regex `^ab` means match any string starting with `ab` so it matches `abc`, `abc123` etc. b) Yes `|` means OR in regex c) Yes that is an alternative but I prefer `mod_rewrite` rules as it is more powerful and feature rich.

Comment: thanks! and how would I block a "blank" agent? do you recommend it? (they always seem to be hacking tools on my logs)

Comment: Great, just tested this, the server returns a 500 error though, shouldn't it be a 403 forbidden? (it says forbidden but in the log its a 500)

Comment: This rule isn't causing any 500 but you might have some other code/rule.

Comment: I've just cleared almost all my .htaccess besides that rule, and this is still the same 500, where else could this rule be?

Comment: Try edited code now. Somewhere in your server config wrong `ErrorDocument` is being used and causing this 500.

Comment: thanks! it now returns a 404 instead. is it good to use this "patch", or should I contact my hosting provider to fix that? can you explain how that additional line solved that?

Comment: New condition just makes sure that  rewrite happens only once and doors not happen after another rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

One option to block specific user agents is to use this [tutorial](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/block-bots-with-htaccess.shtml).

```
BrowserMatchNoCase python bad_bot
BrowserMatchNoCase catexplorador bad_bot
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

The `BrowserMatchNoCase` allows case insensitive matches against the user agent.

A second option is to use the [SetEnvIfNoCase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) command

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "python" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "catexplorador" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^$" bad_user
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_bot
```

This example blocks empty referrers (**WARNING! NOT RECOMMENDED**) and user agents that contain either `python` or `catexplorador`. You don't want to block empty referrers because they can be removed automatically by browsers. It also blocks empty user agents using the last line. Browsers can also do this automatically, depending on how they are configured.

Side note: User agents can be spoofed and changed at will and this is not guaranteed to block anything if the user changes their user agent.

`The BrowserMatch is a special cases of the SetEnvIf directive that sets environment variables conditional on the User-Agent HTTP request header.` The `BrowserMatch` can only check the user agent, while the `SetEnvIf` can check other parameters.

Comment: Thanks but I'm a little confused, can you explain BrowserMatch Vs. SetEnvIF Vs. RewriteCond? what's the best practice and why? (I don't want to block blank referrers, but do believe it's better to block blank agents)

Comment: From the [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html) in my answer, `The BrowserMatch is a special cases of the SetEnvIf directive that sets environment variables conditional on the User-Agent HTTP request header.` The `BrowserMatch` can only check the user agent, while the `SetEnvIf` can check other parameters.